# Creating and running a file with command line arguments

Tags: c++, linux, command-line, fedora

I am very new to linux and apologize if my descriptions are not savvy. I will try to be relevantly detailed.

Currently I am working on a terminal using Fedora, and my goal is to create a smaller data set to run a program. I was given an example, and my mentor said that to run the program all I had to do was type "./filename" into the console.

filename has command line arguments as follows: "./main ./textfile1 ./textfile2" Basically, each argument is separated by a space.
I tried recreating this document with similar format, but I am not sure what to save it as, nor does it work when I try running it the same way as the file with a larger data set.

Also, filename is bold in the terminal, whereas the document I created it is not. I'm not sure if this helps at all, but it is a difference I noticed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the execute bit on your file.

```
chmod +x filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you compile the program first (in case you haven't. I use the g++ compiler typically) and then use the ./filename like your instructor said, but do not put "./" in front of the arguments. Just write it as "./filename textfile1.txt textfile2.txt"

Comment: but the command line arguments are within this file, and it seems that all the previous person had to do was type in the one file that held all of the arguments

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I thought textfile1 and textfile2 were separate files that you were attempting to manipulate (ie: read from or write to). Is that true?

Comment: If you have already hard-coded the paths to those files within your program, then you are right--you dont need them in the command line.